# UWP start application fullscreen and don't show minimize and close button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How can you remove the titlebar and buttons in a UWP application? And always start in fullscreen. In WPF this is easy but can't find how to remove the buttons in UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tre below code in App.Xaml.cs (may be in `onlaunched`)

To remove the **title bar**.

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(null);
```

To make it **full screen** (which also removes buttons)

```
ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Need to import

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
```

Comment: Second option is what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(null);` has no effect. It just resets the title bar back to default in case you had set a custom element as title bar..